# How can I use a one-line with map() to turn all vowels in a string upper case?

Tags: python, mapping

I want to use `map()` to turn all vowels in a string into upper case letter; here is my code:

```
def swap_vowel_case(st):
    listt = "AEIOUaeiou"

    return "".join(list(map(lambda x: x.upper(), vowel) for vowel in listt))
```

This does not work.

Intuitively, I want to write:

```
    return "".join(list(map(lambda x: x.upper() for x in listt,st)))
```

But this doesn't work either. Any ideas how to modify either of the above? Thanks

Comment: Remark: the ```list``` casting is not needed, done automatically

Comment: Is `st` a string or a list of strings?

Comment: `return st.translate(str.maketrans('aeiou', 'AEIOU'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add condition when appending

```
def swap_vowel_case(text):
    vowels = "AEIOUaeiou"
    return "".join(map(lambda char: char.upper() if char in vowels else char, text))


a = swap_vowel_case("But this doesn't work either. Any ideas how to modify either of the above? Thanks")
print(a)
```

Output

```
BUt thIs dOEsn't wOrk EIthEr. Any IdEAs hOw tO mOdIfy EIthEr Of thE AbOvE? ThAnks
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I was doing 'for' loop instead of if statement

Comment: Side note: You can just have `vowels="aeiou"`. "AEIOU" is already upper case.

Comment: @if fhhf mix up with list comprehension? :)